# How to translate a DOM reference to a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have this code:

```
        // Mark all menu items inactive
        $(".sidebar-nav li").removeClass(); 

        // Mark current memu item active
        event.currentTarget.className = "active";
```

Before that, I used to have this code:

```
       $(".sidebar-nav li").css("background", "#383B4C");
       event.currentTarget.style.background = "#292B3C";
```

See the pattern? The first line in both examples is a jQuery selector and so a jQuery method is used; the second line is a DOM reference, and so no jquery. So the syntax is different, even though the action is sort of the same.

This, to me, is a bit of a code smell. I want to either do both the jQuery way, or both the non-jQuery way, so that they look alike. Is there a clean and concise way to accomplish either or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery way**

Wrap `event.currentTarget` with `$(...)`

```
$(".sidebar-nav li").removeClass(); 
$(event.currentTarget).addClass("active");

$(".sidebar-nav li").css("background", "#383B4C");
$(event.currentTarget).css('background',  "#292B3C");
```

**javascript way**

Use [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to make your life easier

```
   var lis = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-nav li");
   for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
       lis[i].className = '';
   }
   event.currentTarget.className = "active";

   for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
       lis[i].style.background = '#383B4C';
   }
   event.currentTarget.style.background = "#292B3C";
```

Comment: I feel stupid. I did not know you can do that. Thank you!

Comment: You're forgetting about `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: @ТаняТ., don't, it took me a while to learn about it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a DOM element to jQuery:

```
$(event.currentTarget)
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap the current target with the jquery selector to convert it to a jquery object

```
$(event.currentTarget).addClass('active')
$(event.currentTarget).css('background', '#292B3C')
```